# NSWindow is not displaying

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am having a trouble try to display a NSWindow with out using Interface Builder. The initialization of the window was quite confusing since I am more familiar with iPhone (which does not have an NSWindow equivalent). So I searched Google for some code and I eventually found this:

```
NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(10.0f, 10.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f);

NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect 
                                               styleMask:( NSResizableWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask) 
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

So I copied that code and placed it in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and thought all would be good. But all is not good. Xcode did not display any errors (or warnings) in the Build Results. But, I do get this message in the display log:

```
2010-06-26 13:33:47.170 FooApp[283:a0f] Could not connect the action buttonPressed: to target of class NSApplication
```

I don't know how to interpret this as Google has failed me on searching for a solution on this display log error. And, as far as I can tell, I have no actions at the moment including a `buttonPressed` one. As a side note: I do not know if this is relevant or not, but I deleted the Main Window.xib and its accompanying property in the info.plist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried doing some `printf` debugging (never really bothered learning `NSLog`) and the thing won't even `printf` if the thing is at the very beginning of the `appliactionDidFinishLaunching` or even worst, at the start of `main` (before the return if incase some of you are tempted to ask me if I put the printf before or after the `return` statement).

Comment: @Dave DeLong: That whole segment is pretty much it. Just began the project you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MainWindow.xib is part of the iphone App template, isn't it? What exactly did you delete? You still have the MainMenu.xib, right?

As you have discovered, having a nib file is not optional for a Cocoa app. You must have at least one nib (or xib, for you youngsters) and it must have a main menu in it.

Comment: No.I know longer have MainMenu.xib I deleted it because I am trying to figure how to do something without it.

Comment: You need it, it has the main menu in. Every Cocoa app has to have a main menu.

Comment: Really, that seems so strange considering iPhone apps you don't need any .xibs technically. Are you sure? Because that does not seem to add up quite right.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. How many mac apps with gui can you count that don't have a menu bar?

Comment: O yeah it does work when I create a new project and not delete the MainWindow.nib! Sorry, I'm just very skeptical and stubborn. And lazy. :P

Comment: I'd accidentally unset the project's "Main Interface" setting and it gave me the same error.